# Is there an Emacs mode for .tac files in Twisted?

Tags: python, emacs, twisted

I've been working through the Twisted tutorials and have gotten to finger11.tac, linked [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/intro.html). Does anyone know if there's an Emac's mode that will do tabs and syntax highlighting for the .tac file type?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a regular python source file so this should do the trick:

`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tac$" . python-mode))`

Comment: Indeed: "A `T`wisted `A`pplication `C`onfiguration is a Python source file, generally with the `.tac` extension, which defines configuration to make an application runnable using twistd." --[twistd glossary](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/glossary.html#core-howto-glossary-tac)

Comment: You can also just put your TAC files into `.py` files.  The `--python/-y` option doesn't actually care what your file's extension is.  (The reason we suggest a non-`.py` extension is that it shouldn't be importable as a module; since it's loaded with `execfile` and not `import` that would mean two copies of your code.  One easy way to ensure that won't happen is to put a dash or a space into its name so it won't be a valid module name.)